Can we catch signals from a cellphone using an external device?
What if someone stole em waves from our mobile devices to listen to our conversations or get our OTP. Whatever encryptions they have they are just EM waves innit and they cannot be propagated only in one direction. They have a range in which we can access this wave. Based on the patterns of these waves one can train an ai to decode these waves to information. Is it possible to make a fake receiver and receive all the data from some one else's cell phone?
I don't have even the basics of antenna technology. Here's what I think would be possible.

Create a receiver antennae using primitive technology.
Tune it to match cellphone frequency.
Analyse the waves and search for patterns.
Feed it to a Neural Network (We can train using our own data.)
Decode the informations.

Is it possible to do So?

This is not an appropriate question for the Physics Stack Exchange. If you clarify your question, it could be appropriate to ask at the Information Security Stack Exchange.

Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_phone_tracker ?

I also think this question is off-topic for Physics, but FWIW, "AI" doesn't change anything here. You don't need "intelligence" to crack modern, mathematical cryptography; You need massive computing power—more computing power than most individuals or corporations can afford. If your conversations are being encrypted for privacy, then AI won't help an eavesdropper to crack them. And, if they are merely being encoded for other, technical reasons, then the cracker won't need AI to look up the relevant technical standards, and use them to listen-in on your calls.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not physics in any sense I can associate with that word, and I am trying to be very polite.

Although it isn't physics, it already exists. It's called wiretapping. Also, nobody uses OTP encryption - AES is the standard.

In principle, this is all possible given enough time and money. But the cost will outweigh any possible gains by many orders of magnitude. And any really valuable data (e.g. inter-bank transactions) will not be transmitted over a mobile phone network anyway.

Steps 1-4 are possible, but, depending on the strength of the encryption, the neural network won't be able to accomplish step 5.
Though it's debatable whether constructing a radio receiver is "primitive" technology.

A basic radio receiver is, in terms of electronics-enabled technology, pretty primitive compared to our omniscient always-listening supercomputers that can perform billions of operations per second, access the entire database of all human knowledge as well as virtually all applications ever created, and fit in out pockets.

"Stole em waves" - You shouldn't think of this like stealing money from the bank. It is more like listening in on a conversation. Both the cell phone and whoever is talking to it send EM waves out in all directions for anyone to pick up.
One way to protect yourself is to encrypt the messages. Sort of like translating English to Martian. Only you and your friends understand Martian.

It's not "stealing" in the sense of stealing a bicycle, nor is it "stealing" in the sense of stealing somebody's idea, or stealing the credit for some accomplishment, or even stealing somebody's heart. It's more like stealing cable TV or stealing secrets.
